# Concatenate two Excel spreadsheet data (side by side)

Tags: python, excel, pandas

I am trying to figure out how I can combine data from two spreadsheets side by side. I know how to write and save into a specific file name using Pandas, but am not sure how to combine them. E.g.:

Sheet 1:

```
avgdegf |  50 | 
76      |  20 |
68      |  30 |
39      |  40 |
```

Sheet 2:

```
temp    |  32 | 
26      |  20 |
28      |  32 |
32      |  41 |
```

Resulting in:

```
    avgdegf |  50 | temp| 32 |
    76      |  20 | 26  | 20 |
    68      |  30 | 28  | 32 |
    39      |  40 | 32  | 41 |
```

I know that you can save into another spreadsheet by using (general example):

```
writer = ExcelWriter('file name.xlsx')
df.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1',index=False)
writer.save()
```

Comment: Sorry are you looking to `concat`: `merged = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)`?

Comment: Yes I am looking for concatenation, thanks for the technical term!

Comment: So does `merged = pd.concat([df,df1], axis=1)` do what you want?

Comment: It merges the files, but the issue is that when I do this with multiple columns with the same values it 'tries' to put things in order', when all i want is to put the 2nd file contents in front of the first file contents, without sorting